# Asymptotic. If f(n) = theta(g(n)) and g(n) = theta(h(n)), then why h(n) = theta(f(n))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

it is f(n)=theta(h(n)) as theta is transitive. But Can any one explain why h(n)=theta(f(n)).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science. Consider migrating it to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All of the growth notations are transitive.  Theta is the only one that is also symmetric (and tilde, if that counts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding the Big-O notation by its definition usually makes things easy.

[image]

Comment: putting H(n)<=G(n)/s.. cool..and easy ..thanks @Skyler.Is it why the theta is symmetric ..

Comment: very nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If k1.h(n) <= f(n) <= k2.h(n) for large n, then (1/k2)f(n) <= h(n) <= (1/k1)f(n).

Answer (score 0):

That's basically simply because `f(n) € theta(h(n))` is equivalent to `h(n) € theta(f(n))` because of the following:

```
f(n) € O(h(n)) => h(n) € Omega(f(n))
f(n) € Omega(h(n)) => f(n) € O(h(n))
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I didn't pay attention at this very moment. Can I reject it now?

Comment: Nope; we had to clean up the tag to remove the spam. If you are not paying attention, why review at all?